# Loader using Protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, static, protocols

I want to use protocol for the view controllers just for showing and hiding the loader. I am successful up to this part. But I would like to restrict the execution of the loader function if it is already showing the loader.

I call the showLoader function for API requests. And I don't want to hide the loader until all requests got a response. Can I achieve this If I am using the count variable as static? Or is there any other way to achieve this without the count? or even it is possible or not, please advise.

```
protocol Loader where Self: UIViewController {
    func showLoader()
    func hideLoader()
}

extension Loader {
    func showLoader() {
        if count == 0 {
            print("Show Loading")
        }
        count += 1
    }

    func hideLoader() {
        count -= 1
        if count < 1 {
            count = 0
            print("Hide Loading")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Where to declare `count`?

Comment: Make `count` part of the protocol?

Comment: I have edited a bit more for your question. @jnpdx

Comment: "use the count variable as static" -- is that really what you want? Or, do you just want to know how to make a variable part of the protocol like @JoakimDanielson suggested?

Comment: `I would like to use the count variable as static` seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Seems you only need a counter that will increase and decrease based on the `showLoader`/`hideLoader` calls, and show/hide the loading view based on the counter value. Not yet clear why you'd need a protocol for this, can you show us some code samples on how do you plan to use it, assuming it works?

Comment: @Cristik I don't want to use a base view controller just to handle Loader and inherit that base view controller to all other view controllers. If you think what I am tying is not possible, please explain so that I will drop this idea with clear knowledge. Thanks 

Comment: I wasn't necessarily referring to subclassing. Anyhow, others have given you good suggestions about how to solve this with protocols, e.g. by making `count` part of the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't really need to care about this. You can have a class that internally handles if there is an loader already in place by removing it before show it.

```
class Loader {
    // This is your view which can contain an animation or just the spinner
    private static var activityView: LoaderView!

    static func showLoader(onView view: UIView) {
        removeLoader()
        // The params are frame and superview
        activityView = LoaderView(with: view.bounds, view)
        view.addSubview(activityView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            activityView.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }

    static func removeLoader() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            // if exists it will be removed, if not is nil and nothing will happened.
            activityView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already using the base class for the loader. But I am trying to achieve this through the protocol.